# react chartjs data from api

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, bar-chart

[image]I am using chartjs 2 in a react application and trying to render a bar chart with two values for correct answers and wrong answers. If for some reason the chart is rendering only one bar. It is showing the other value but it is not rendering it. I am rendering the chart in useEffect hook. The chart is working fine if I hard code the values.

```
const options = {
        tooltip:{display:false},
        legend: {display:false},
        title: {
             display:true,
             text:title,
             fontSize:24
         }
         
     }

     setOpt(options);

    
        setData({
            labels: dt,
            datasets: [
                {
                  type: 'bar',
                  label: "Correct",
                  backgroundColor: 'rgb(4,240,106,0.6)',
                  data: cor
                },
                {
                  type: 'bar',
                  label: "Wrong",
                  backgroundColor: 'rgb(236,9,9,0.6)',
                  data: wro
                  }
                
            ]
        })
    
    }
```

The data is coming from an api.

```
var corr = [];
                var wrr = [];
                var dt = [];


            if(once && exhist.length === 0){
            var url = `http://localhost:3292/ExamService.svc/gethistory/${user}/20AC4821-BB0F-4A88-BF5A-319D0301B5C5`;
            fetch(url).then((result) => result.json())
            .then(value => {
                setEHistory(value);
                setOnce(false);
            })
        } else {

                exhist.map(eh => {
                    setTitle("Exam One");
                    corr.push(eh.Correct + 5);
                    wrr.push(eh.Wrong);
                    var d = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(new Date(eh.Resdate));
                    dt.push(d);
                })

                setCor(corr);
                setWro(wrr);
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example or at least show us the contents of `cor` and `wro`?

Comment: Are you using react-chartjs-2. Either way, you'll want to useState on the options with a default state of the structure, and the update/set the new state on the params that you need to manipulate.

Comment: I am initializing the chart in the useState and trying to get it updated in useEffect. In the picture you can see the that the data is there but it is not being rendered.